# Make an exception in Windows Authentication in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, iis-8.5, intranet

I have a .Net 4.5 intranet application that uses Windows authentication. Works fine. However, today I was asked if it is possible to allow a generic user ID, that is not in AD, to have access to one of the pages that lists a bunch of reports.

They are installing large screen monitors in some facilitates to stream dashboards off of the website. Those computers use a generic username login.

Can authentication in IIS be tweaked to allow a specific username outside AD? I tried the following in web.config but it did not help (I used both '*' and '?')

```
<location path="ReportsFileName.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: It may be easier to use a "non-human ID" or service account ID - the idea is to join those computers to the domain, and whatever account they use to get to the desktop is something not assigned to a person.

Comment: [Mixing Forms and Windows Security in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx)

Comment: that's one of the things I suggested to them; we have used those accounts when anonymous authentication was on for some web sites and service accounts (user ID and password) were used to query AD. I am trying to see if there are alternatives.

Comment: they want single sign on (SSO), no forms authentication if user is already logged in on a corporate desktop/laptop.